# Running MS-DOS games with long file names under DOSBox

Tags: dosbox, msdos

I'm trying to play a DOS game under DOSBox that uses long filenames. Here's the ISO as seen from macOS:

[image: macOS]

The ISO as `imgmount`ed inside DOSBox:

[image: DOSBox]

I'm trying to start *install.bat* but I can't figure out how to do it. Based on the fact that it's a DOS game and it uses long filenames, I suspect that it was made for MS-DOS 7.

How do I install and run this game?

---

**Edit**: I noticed something odd. When I extract the ISO's folder structure and mount them, the directory structure looks normal. But for reasons beyond the scope of this post (the soundtrack being one of them), I need the actual ISO for the game to function properly.

Here's the directory listing if I just mount the extracted contents of the ISO with `mount`:

[image: DOSBox with mount]

Comment: Alternatively, you can type part of the filename (e.g. `ins`) and hit the TAB key on your keyboard. The command line interface should autocomplete the filename. It's possible the reason `install6` doesn't work is because it should be `INSTALL6` or `install6.bat` instead. The TAB key would fix mistakes like that.

Comment: It almost looks like DOSBox is having issues with the files as the file extensions are being stripped.

Comment: I agree with Powerlord.  What are the results of typing `dir /x`?

Comment: Side note: Are you using the DOSBox [`imgmount`](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/IMGMOUNT) command to mount the ISO or something else?

Comment: I agree with the comments. There's something wonky going on with how DOSBox sees the files. 7 characters +  3 character extensions should _not_ need shortening in DOS. Also, the `install.bat` doesn't run, because DOS deosn't know it's a `.bat` thanks to the shortening.

Comment: Yes, I am using `imgmount`. `ins` completes to `INSTALL6`, but when executing it I just get a `Illegal command` error.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Regarding the `dir /x`: DOSBox doesn't recognize the `/x` switch.

Comment: How are you mounting?  Are you using `imgmount drive imageName -t iso -fs iso`?

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Initially did it with `imgmount drive imageName -t iso` (without the `-fs`), but your way of mounting seems to have the same effect.

Comment: I've always just used `mount`. Extract and mount it as C: then install it from 'c:' after you mount the ISO as D:

Comment: Seems like a weird issue with mounting. Are you using vanilla DosBox, SVN or Boxer? I wonder if trying a different build would help, especially Boxer. Also a sidenote if you are trying to run a game that uses cd audio you can't use ISO format (data track only). You'll have to use CUE/BIN.

Answer (score -4):

This needs to be installed under Windows (autorun.exe). Start Windows, insert the CD / floppy, and then run autorun.exe (it may also be automatically run). Make sure you use Windows 95. It has support for long filenames. Don't use 3.11.

Comment: The presence of an `autorun.exe` file doesn't mean that the program requires Windows, just that it will do something automatically (usually, launch the program or an installer) under Windows.

Comment: A lot of games back then had more than one method of installing to cope with the DOS/Win3x/Win9x situation.